# How to convert object to float without causing error?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have problem to converting the objects in one column to float. There is no ',' or empty space problem, and when I go through the data one by one, or use a for loop to print the float of each object it is possible, but astype does not work and produce ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Null' error. Do you know why?

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import seaborn as sns

df1=pd.read_csv('../input/smart-meters-in-london/halfhourly_dataset/halfhourly_dataset/block_10.csv')

energy=df1.loc[:,"energy(kWh/hh)"]
df1['energy']=energy
df1= df1.set_index("tstp")
df1=df1.drop('energy(kWh/hh)', axis=1)
#this works
for i in df1.loc[:, 'energy']:
    print(float(i))
#but not
df1.energy=df1.energy.astype(float64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a list out of those values why not use `map()`? Simply, you can try:

`list(map(float, df1.loc[:, 'energy']))`

I think this will return a list with the objects in that column as float.
`map()` returns a map object, so you need `list()`

Comment: This is really not how you should be working with pandas at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
df1["energy"] = df1["energy"].astype(float64)
```

Comment: Do you know how can I split the data in energy column to separated columns based on the values in LCLid column, and attach the new columns to the dataframe? I used Loc and for loop for finding the corresponding values for each unique LCLid, but the length does not match. Also using map and apply, but apparently using wrong, since I get again error. Do you have an idea how can I solve it?